# I have a foreach loop in my view which gnerates a table,I want to pass some rows in that table to jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a foreach loop in my view
It generates a table.
In my table in each row i have a checkbox 
If that check box is checked i have to pass that particular row to jquery 
If multiple rows are checked i have to pass multiple rows.
can you please guide me how to do this.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Okay... so suppose you have this table

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectedItem"/></td>
    <td>100</td><td>Apple</td><td>Fruit</td>
<tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectedItem"/></td>
    <td>101</td><td>Cabbage</td><td>Veggie</td>
<tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectedItem"/></td>
    <td>102</td><td>Orange</td><td>Fruit</td>
<tr>
</table>
```

This is how you can gather your data into a jquery object.

```
function collectItems() {
    // placeholder for your selected items
    var items = [];

    // query for selected items (checked checkboxes)
    $('[name="selectedItem"]:checked').each(function() {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');                                
        var item = {
            id: row.find('td:nth-child(2)').text(),
            name: row.find('td:nth-child(3)').text(),
            category: row.find('td:nth-child(4)').text(),
        };                
        items.push(item);
    });       
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is very helpful,can you please tell me one more thing 
I want to know hoe to pass multiple rows if more than one check box is checked
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That code already handles that. Notice the array declared as `items=[]` and then an `item` object is pushed to it in the loop. I put a comment "query for selected items (checked checkboxes)" notice there's an "s" that means it will handle multiple checked checkboxes. ;)

Comment: How do i need to handle this array in controller can you please help me